# error message when trying to create a new environment with conda

Tags: python, conda

I am trying to create a new environment with conda instruction (on Mac M1):
`conda create  --name tf2 python==3.9`
but I get an error message:

```
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python==3.9

Current channels:

  - defaults

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

why and what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Use one equal sign:

```bash
conda create -n tf2 python=3.9
```

Conda syntax is not the same as Pip. In Conda, two equal signs means exact match and `3.9` is not a proper version. The first in the series was 3.9.0, and 3.9.6 was the first **osx-arm64** build on the `defaults` channel. However, most users almost always want the latest patch, and that is what `python=3.9` will give. That is, Conda interprets it as `3.9.*`.